# Updating a node and its accompanying indexes in neo4j using neography

Tags: neo4j, neography

How do I update a given property of a node using neography? And if its an indexed field. will the indexes get updated automatically?

I know on the console, its as trivial as

```
  cd -a 15
  set username foobar
```

Of course this doesnt update any indexes(indices sp?) either.

Comment: Just found the set_node_properties method in neography. Must've missed it earlier. But it still doesnt update the indexes. Are you expected to remove and add the node to indexes yourself?

Answer (score 0):

According to the neo4j-manual-1.8

> To update an index entry, the old one must be removed and a new one
>   added

Another option is to setup autoindexing.